# Javascript map question returning an array with empty values

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to use .map to create a new array called `workspaces` that just has the id in the array however the code below whilst the console.log() works fine and shows the id in the console.log as expected when I use the `return` it doesn't show these ids in the workspaces array

```
    const workspaces = this.networkTree.map( (group) => {
      group.units.map( (unit) => {
        console.log(unit.id);   // outputs an id to the console e.g '12345'
        return unit.id;
      });
    });

    console.log(workspaces);   // each array is empty (see image below)
```

[image]

Comment: Your outer map doesn't return anything. `const workspaces = this.networkTree.map( group => group.units.map( unit => unit.id) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care to return the result from the nested map, like so:

```
const workspaces = this.networkTree.map( (group) => {
  return group.units.map( (unit) => { // <= the `return` here
    console.log(unit.id);
    return unit.id;
  });
});

console.log(workspaces);
```

An alternative would be if you don't add braces to the inline function:

```
const workspaces = this.networkTree.map( (group) => 
  group.units.map( (unit) => {
    console.log(unit.id);
    return unit.id;
  })
);
```

And when you decide to remove the `console.log`:

```
const workspaces = this.networkTree.map( (group) => group.units.map( (unit) => unit.id));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return statement:

```js
const workspaces = this.networkTree.map((group) => {
    return group.units.map((unit) => {
        return unit.id;
    });
});
```

Or, because you are using arrow functions:

```js
const workspaces = this.networkTree.map((group) => group.units.map((unit) => unit.id));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason is that you did not return the new `group` with the new `unit` (in the outer map).
You can, for instance, change the braces in the outer map to parentheses for an `auto return`

```
const workspaces = this.networkTree.map( (group) => ( // opening (
      group.units.map( (unit) => {
        console.log(unit.id); 
        return unit.id;
      });
    )); // closing )
```

Comment: Like this, you are ignoring the result of `group.units.map`.

Comment: Thank you @ErnestoStifano, I just tried it in the console and I found out that the return would rather be in line 2 before group.units.map